# Remove jQuery UI Dialog Button border/outline

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-button

Which class do I need to modify/change to remove the outline of a JQuery UI Dialog Button.  I can't seem to figure out which class is applying the border/outline around the 'X' button.  The outline goes away when I click on the button.

I'm using this CSS: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my own question.  Turns out that **outline-color** doesn't have a transparent/none option, so I had to override **outline-width** for the classes.  So I set

```
outline-width: 0px !important;
```

Comment: What about `outline:none;`

Comment: Just to bring it all together, the exact CSS rule which solved this for me: `.ui-dialog-titlebar > .ui-button { outline-width: 0px !important; }`

Answer (score 3):

The code applying the border to that button is (it includes other things, but I'm putting just the relevant part here):

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}
```

And in that case, the `<button>` element matches all 3 selectors, so you could use a selector like this:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar > .ui-button {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

To override the default style **just** for the dialog buttons...

**[Jsbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ohorin/1/edit)**

Comment: Actually, turns out it was **outline-width** that I needed to modify (I kept trying to override border and outline-color, but you can't set outline-color to transparent/none apparently).
Thanks though.

Comment: What about `outline:none;`

Answer (score 1):

this css works for me.

```
        <style type="text/css">
          .ui-widget-content {
            border: none !important;
          }
        </style>
```

Comment: Thank you from my bottom of heart. You are so my hero today.

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery UI Tabs which are actually links this works:

```
<style>
    a.ui-tabs-anchor{
        outline: none !important;
    }
</style>
```